# avoid anti arrow pattern

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

I have pattern template method that implemets base functionality for different types of chart. Each chart type `FastChart`, `SlowChart` implements zooming function `Zoom()` this function should make different zoom on different Series `AreaSeries`,`CandleStickSeries`.

I think that

```
    public override void Zoom()
    {
        if (BTF.AreaSeries != null)
        {

        }
        if (BTF.CandleStickSeries!=null)
        { 

        }
    }
```

very bad idea because if i should have 10 types of series i should make 10 `if` statement in each function. How to avoid this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication38765
{
public interface IFirstType
{
    AreaSeries AreaSeries { get; set; }
    CandleStickSeries CandleStickSeries { get; set; }
}
public class BoxTypeFirst : IFirstType
{
    public AreaSeries AreaSeries { get; set; }
    public CandleStickSeries CandleStickSeries { get; set; }
}
public interface IChart
{
    void Zoom();
    void DrawChart();
    void GetPoints();
}
public interface IRectangle
{
    void AddRectangles();
}
public abstract class BaseChart:IChart
{
    public abstract void Zoom();

    public virtual void DrawChart()
    {
    }

    public  virtual void GetPoints()
    {
    }
}
public class FastChart:BaseChart
{
    BoxTypeFirst BTF = new BoxTypeFirst();
    public override void Zoom()
    {
        if (BTF.AreaSeries != null)
        {

        }
    }
}
public class SlowChart:BaseChart,IRectangle
{
    BoxTypeFirst BTF = new BoxTypeFirst();

    public override void Zoom()
    {
        if (BTF.CandleStickSeries != null)
        {

        }
    }
    public void AddRectangles()
    {

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseChart BS = new SlowChart();
        BS.Zoom();
        BS = new FastChart();
        BS.Zoom();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can your chart contain more than one series-type? (if yes: Visitor-Pattern - if not make your derived charts generic in the used series-type ~> no if at all required)

Comment: @A191919 From what you describe, you're not avoiding the Arrow Anti-pattern.  This anti-pattern necessarily requires If-statements to be nested.  I think you should consider changing the mis-leading title.

Comment: @Carsten no it should have only one series type. I will try generic.

Comment: @Ian what title i should make?

Comment: @A191919 ... something that doesn't involve any of those words!

Comment: @A191919 Couldn't you delegate the zoom to the BTF?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an option you can let BaseChart what series it uses and to check for null there.

```
public abstract class BaseChart
{
    public void Zoom()
    {
        if (Series != null)
        {
            OnZoom();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnZoom();

    public virtual void DrawChart()
    {
    }

    protected abstract object Series { get; }

    public virtual void GetPoints()
    {
    }
}

public class FastChart : BaseChart
{
    private readonly BoxTypeFirst BTF = new BoxTypeFirst();

    protected override void OnZoom()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override object Series
    {
        get { return BTF.AreaSeries; }
    }
}

public class SlowChart : BaseChart
{
    private readonly BoxTypeFirst BTF = new BoxTypeFirst();

    protected override void OnZoom()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override object Series
    {
        get { return BTF.CandleStickSeries; }
    }
}
```

But anyway your code design smells. I don't see whole picture so I cannot say much about it.